# Is "salience" property unavailable for Japanese?

Tags: google-cloud-nl

I tried Google NLP API on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/). And I found that when I try a Japanese sentence, all the responses' "salience" property would be `0`. Is there any problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salience is currently unavailable in Japanese, sorry. We hope to fix that soon, but I don't have a specific date I can give you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.